# Issue with Updating file in ADLS Gen2 using Rest-API

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I'm using ADLS Gen2 using rest api Path-Update i'm trying to update data into already created created blank file into ADLS.
but whenever i'm trying to use the API i'm getting below response from API.
**{StatusCode: 202, ReasonPhrase: 'Accepted'}**
but still the file will be empty.

```
string requestUri = "https://XXXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/XXXXX/abc.txt?action=append&position=0";// &retainUncommittedData=false&close=true";
            dynamic method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
            dynamic request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("\"requestBody\":\"test\"")
            };`enter code here`
            // Add some defined headers
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationToken);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

            // Add some other headers or custom headers
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", "0");

            dynamic httpClient = new HttpClient();
            dynamic result = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

i expect the data should be updated in file but now i'm getting 202 Accepted as a response code but file is not updated with data

also i tried append with flush operation below is the code i'm getting 405 error

```
string requestUri = "https://XXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/XXXXX/abc.txt?action=append&position=0";// &retainUncommittedData=false&close=true";
        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("\"requestBody\":\"test\"")
        };

        // Add some defined headers
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationToken);
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));

        // Add some other headers or custom headers
        // request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", "0");

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

        string requestUri1 = "https://XXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/XXXXXX/abc.txt?action=flush&position=0";//&retainUncommittedData=false&close=true";
        using (HttpClient httpClient1 = new HttpClient())
        {

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = (httpClient.PutAsync(requestUri1, null)).Result;


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

If the files in adls gen2 is empty, you can use the method below:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var auth = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();          

            const string url = "https://storage.azure.com/";
            string token = auth.GetAccessTokenAsync(url).Result;
            string requestUri = "https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/t11/c.txt?action=append&position=0";
            var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

            string upload_string = "have a nice day!";

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(upload_string)
            };

            // Add some defined headers
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
            var i = request.Content.AsString().Length;
            Console.WriteLine(request.Content.AsString());

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var result = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

            Console.WriteLine("append result status code: "+ (int)result.StatusCode);

            //for flush    
            string requestUri_2 = "https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/t11/c.txt?action=flush&position="+upload_string.Length;

            var request_2 = new HttpRequestMessage(method,requestUri_2);

            using (HttpClient httpClient_2 = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient_2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient_2.SendAsync(request_2).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("flush result status code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
            }

          Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Test result as below, and I also check in azure, the data is flushed into the file.

[image]

---

Once you have received the 202 Accepted you can then call the `action=flush` and pass the position that you want the data to be flushed to. like below:

```
https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata/data/file1?action=flush&position=10
```

Comment: thanks @Ivan yes i don't have any data in my file previously added so i guess no need of flush.

Comment: @MBG The flush action is needed. append just prepares the data, flush is actually used to uploaded the data to file.

Comment: even i tried flush operation after append but i'm getting some error as **The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.**                                                                             do i have to add any of the parameter with the same.

Comment: please find the above snippet for your reference.

Comment: @MBG, ok I will take a try at my side, and will update you later.

Comment: @MBG, if the file in adls gen2 is empty, I figure out how to solve the issue. But if the file in adls gen2 is not empty, I'm always getting 400 error: position is not correct. I'll post my code in my answer later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196700/discussion-between-mbg-and-ivan-yang).

Comment: however my file will be empty all the time. just wanted to add data into it.

Comment: @MBG, let chat in the chat room

Comment: @MBG, if the file on adls gen2 is empty, then my solution is working for you.